# How to create a startscript for ipython qtconsole in windows7?

Tags: windows-7, ipython

I want to start ipython without to open the windows console (cmd) and typing this command:

```
ipython qtconsole
```

Is it possible to create a programm which I can click and that opens ipython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following as somefile.reg and doubleclick the file. It will add a reference to the registry to allow you to right click on an open directory and select "Open Ipython Notebook" to launch a new instance in that directory.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\ipynb]
@="Open IPython Notebook"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\ipynb\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe ipython notebook"
```

I cannot remember who I got the tip from, so I am sorry for the lack of acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Python3 and IPython3. IPython4 has some strange behave.

There are two way to make the goal.

**The First, Make a shortcut.** Create a shortcut and type in below:

```
C:\Python34\pythonw.exe -m IPython qtconsole
```

Change the path of your PythonW.exe and be careful of the **letter case** of "IPython" word. Then lock it in the taskbar or startbar.

**The Second, Make a Registry.** Create a new file named with ext as .reg, type in below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\ipyqt]
@="在此開啟 IPython 窗口"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\ipyqt\command]
@="C:\\Python34\\pythonw.exe -m IPython qtconsole"
```

The first @= string, means Open IPython Window Here, Change with what you like.
The second @= string, the command, change the path if you need.
Then you can click your right mouse key and open a bare ipython qtconsole which's work directory is the directory you click right key.

Suggest The Second Way, and forget about the grammar error.